# Why is there unreachable code here?

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# app and want to output error messages to either the console or a messagebox (Depending on the app type: enum AppTypeChoice { Console, Windows } ), and also control wether the app keeps running or not ( bool StopOnError ).

I came up with this method that will check all the criteria, but I'm getting an "unreachable code detected" warning. I can't see why!

Here is the whole method (Brace yourselves for some hobbyist code!)

```
    public void OutputError(string message)
    {
        string standardMessage = "Something went WRONG!. [ But I'm not telling you what! ]";
        string defaultMsgBoxTitle = "Aaaaarrrggggggggggg!!!!!";
        string dosBoxOutput = "\n\n*** " + defaultMsgBoxTitle + " *** \n\n Message was: '" + message + "'\n\n";
        AppTypeChoice appType = DataDefs.AppType;
        DebugLevelChoice level = DataDefs.DebugLevel;

        // Decide how much info we should give out here...
        if (level != DebugLevelChoice.None)
        {
            // Give some info....
            if (appType == AppTypeChoice.Windows)
                MessageBox.Show(message, defaultMsgBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(dosBoxOutput);
        }
        else
        {
            // Be very secretive...
            if (appType == AppTypeChoice.Windows)
                MessageBox.Show(standardMessage, defaultMsgBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(standardMessage);
        }

        // Decide if app falls over or not..
        if (DataDefs.StopOnError == true)
            Environment.Exit(0); // UNREACHABLE CODE HERE
    }
```

Also, while I have your attention, to get the app type, I'm just using a constant at the top of the file (ie. AppTypeChoice.Console in a Console app etc) - is there a better way of doing this (i mean finding out in code if it is a DOS or Windows app)?

Also, I noticed that I can use a messagebox with a fully-qualified path in a Console app...How bad is is to do that ( I mean, will I get tarred and feathered when other developers see it?!)

Thanks for your help

Comment: By the way, there's no point in writing `if (something == true)`.  You can simply write `if (something)`.

Answer (score 10):

`DataDefs.StopOnError` is a compile-time constant equal to `false`.

Therefore, the compiler replaces it with `false` (Or whatever you set it to) near the begining of the compiliation process.

Therefore, your code compiles to:

```
if (false == true)
    Environment.Exit(0); // UNREACHABLE CODE HERE
```

This is obviously unreachable.

The simplest solution is to make the `DataDefs.StopOnError` field `readonly` instead of `const`.

The compiler will only give this warning if all of the values involved are compile-time constants or literals, so using any other type of field for `DataDefs.StopOnError` will stop the warning.

Comment: Ah...So when does it become the value I want it to be?
or how do I make it the value I ant it to be?

Answer (score 2):

If the value of `DataDefs.StopOnError` is false, then the body of the "if" will be unreachable.  Check to see if that's the default.

Comment: Yes, but only if it's `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Look specifically at this code...

```
DebugLevelChoice level = DataDefs.DebugLevel;

        // Decide how much info we should give out here...
        if (level != DebugLevelChoice.None)
```

The code above will be unreachable because you set `level` to always be `DebugLevel` so it'll never be `None`.  It'd help us further if you could tell us more about what the error says, for example, what lines its on or which code is unreachable.

Comment: Wrong.  Since it's not `const`, that will not give an error.  (I checked)

Comment: -1. How would the compiler know whether DataDefs.DebugLevel can ever be None or not? Also, the unreachable code is not inside that if statement at all.

Comment: @Joren: It doesn't, and that's not where the error is.  This answer is wrong.

Comment: Ok, the Debuglevel is a const in the DataDefs class, set to 
<pre><code>
public const DebugLevelChoice DebugLevel = DebugLevelChoice.All; // ie. show ALL output</code></pre>

Comment: Yes, but the `level` variable is not `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're using a constant in a conditional statement is exactly why you're seeing this message. The compiler's telling you that the one of the paths in that statement can never be executed as this would often indicate a logic problem.

So, if as you say you define appType as a constant (AppTypeChoice.Console) then the first clause in this block will never be executed:

```
// Give some info....
if (appType == AppTypeChoice.Windows)
    MessageBox.Show(message, defaultMsgBoxTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
else
    Console.WriteLine(dosBoxOutput);
```

Comment: yeah, I see it now - I want to set that for each program (Console or Windows), and NOT have it as a constant.
Duh! I DO NOT BELIEVE that I missed that!

Thanks, guys

Comment: Thanks to you all for your help - I've just gleaned a little more C# knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the message box, it is not a good idea to use a message box for reporting data from the command line.  When a message box pops up, it will prevent the command line program from finishing execution until the user interacts with it.  This can lead to problems when some other program invokes your program and no one is around to click OK.  It is better to use the console for error output; other developers will thank you for saving them from having to hack around the message box.